# How to enable the an NIC to transmit data received from a port through the other port?

Tags: linux, networking, network-adapter

I have purchased a network interface controller, with two optical fiber interface and one PCI interface. I plan to test its performance through a device manufactured by Spirent. This process requires to configure the NIC so that one of its ports can transmit data received from a port through the other port. However, I do not know how to do it. The operating system I am using is Linux. I would be grateful if you guys could help me with that!

Comment: The canonical tool to configure the NIC hardware is `ethtool`, but I am not aware if it can configure this kind of two-port "loopback". Could you edit your question with the output of `lspci -nn` for this particular card, and the driver used (the two "kernel" lines in `lspci -v`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your NIC to act as a Bridge. Commands to do that depends on your Linux distribution but I found I guess usefull tutorial how to do it: https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/bridge

Comment: That's not the full story – with many NICs, ordinary bridges will still loop the data through the CPU, and depending on what OP needs, that may or may not make a good performance test. Only some multi-port NICs automatically activate hardware switching when a bridge is configured, and some of them require separate tools to do so.

Comment: I have read something related to the term DPDK. I am wondering how to apply this to fulfill my requirement, since I find that using a "bridge" has a high rate of packet loss, low through put rate